# Python, requests получаю непонятные символы вместо русских

Tags: python, requests

Учусь парсингу, но при попытке спарсить сайт получаю вместо русских символов следующее: `"\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd1\x88\xd0\xb8\xd1\x82\xd1\x8c \xd0\xb7\xd0\xb0\xd"`

Мой код:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://rozetka.com.ua/gold_star_2000000005850/p24443545/"
response = requests.get(url)

print(response.text.encode('utf-8'))  # encode Не помог! 
print(response.text)  # то же самое
```

```
Версия python : 3.5.4
requests 2.22.0
```

Редактор Visual Studio Code последней версии, обычный русский текст в консоль выводит без проблем

Comment: `response.text` вывел мне абсолютно валидный и красивый `HTML` с кириллицей (`Python 3.8`, `requests 2.22.0`).

Comment: Спасибо, я тоже за себя очень рад. Но написал я это к тому, чтобы Вы привели больше данных. Ошибка не воспроизводится в стандартных условиях.

Comment: добавил версию python и остальное, даже не знаю, что еще можно

Comment: @CoffeeinTime, ваш код не выдает строку, которую вы показали в вопросе над кодом. Дополните код, чтобы можно было воспроизвести ваш результат.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Бери из `response` байт-строку и декодируй ее в UTF-8:

```py
print(response.content.decode('utf-8'))

>>> <title>ROZETKA | Копилка Gold Star Золотой Батон (2000000005850). Цена, купить Копилка Gold Star Золотой Батон (2000000005850) в Киеве, Харькове, Днепропетровске, Одессе,
```

Оригинал

```py
print(response.text.encode('utf-8'))

>>> <title>ROZETKA | \xd0\x9a\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbf\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbb\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0 Gold Star \xd0\x97\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbe\xd1
```

Если проблема касалась именно этого.